# How the decentralized storage system Storj works?

Tags: blockchain

http://storj.io - it is decentralize data storage system.

How do they distribute data between the network participant? Unlike bitcoin, each network member can not store a copy of the blockchain, the data is too large. It turns out that different participants of the network store different data, but not the same as in bitcoin. But then how do they achieve full decentralization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really long story cut short. In StorJ, Files are stored as Encrypted Shards.
A shard is a portion of an encrypted file to be stored on this network. They use shards along with with a Distributed Hash Table called Kademlia to keep track of shards.

Farmers are given incentives in the form of tokens to store shards.
Storj has over 20,000 tenants and 18,000 farmers. Altogether the Storj network has over 8 Petabytes of storage at its disposal, or roughly 450 GB per farmer.

[image]

You can read more about them here:

- https://coincentral.com/storj-beginners-guide/
- https://storj.io/storj.pdf